# What's the difference b/w ChainType::Development vs Local?

Tags: chainspec

```rust
pub enum ChainType {
    /// A development chain that runs mainly on one node.
    Development,
    /// A local chain that runs locally on multiple nodes for testing purposes.
    Local,
    /// A live chain.
    Live,
    /// Some custom chain type.
    Custom(String),
}
```

The question arises from seeing two separate functions in the node template, `development_config() -> ChainSpec` and `local_config() -> ChainSpec`, where the only difference I could spot was the difference in `ChainType` of the aforementioned `ChainSpec`. Reading the code docs I get that a `Local` is suited for multiple peers, but is there any code that I can look at that specifically makes use of this distinction, i.e. `ChainType::Development` vs `ChainType::Local`?

Answer (score 3):

I can't answer your question perfectly.

It's a marker/property, which means it's hard to find out all usage of it. We don't how many apps use this marker/property.

For example, if your chain type is development, polkadot.js/talisman wallet won't pop up the `update the metadata` window while connecting to a node. This is pretty tricky. I spent a lot of time debugging this last month. The app told me that I need to update the metadata. But I can't update it from the UI. That part was disabled.

Comment: That's quite odd. but at the same time insightful as it at least gives us a clue that polkadot-js is making use of this distinction.